# Meaning output ANOVA post hoc tests

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am carrying out an ANOVA in Mma, and I wanted to apply a post-hoc test, but I do not understand the output that is given.
It says e.g. `Model-> Duncan, {4, 5}` but what would that mean?

Comment: Duncan's test effectively performs the same sequential paired comparisons as the StudentNewmanKeuls test, but with significance levels adjusted at each iteration. You can find more Information [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/ref/Duncan.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/ref/PostTests.html). On statistical issues the guys from [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) can provide better information.

Comment: The point is that I don't get why Mathamtica gives an output such as {4,5}. What does this particular output mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last example in the documentation for the `ANOVA` package  [ANOVA tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ANOVA/tutorial/ANOVA.html):

> [image]
>
> [image: Blockquote]

In your example, `Model-> Duncan, {4, 5}` means (1) you have set the option `PostTests->Duncan` in your code, and (2) *groups 4 and 5 are significantly different at the 100 - x % significance level* where `x` the significance level you have specified as the value of the option `SignificanceLevel` or the default value (which, I think, is`5%`).